# How can I properly replace the hose on this older Schwinn pump?

Tags: repair, pump

I have the following Schwinn bike pump. It’s pretty old, perhaps 30 years or more. I like it a lot.

[image]

Some years ago, I changed to Presta valves; for this I needed a new head. I got a [Topeak SmartHead Bicycle Floor Pump Upgrade Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FIE4JK), which is a replacement head and hose with a number of different adapters. Unfortunately, none of them fit this pump, so I just hacked off most of the worn-out stock hose and spliced in the Topeak hose (one of the adapters is designed for this).

Every so often, the splice begins to leak because the stock hose cracks a little. This is easily repaired by cutting off another 5mm and re-splicing, but obviously that's not sustainable.

Here are some close-up views of the threads, and also the gauge for ID purposes. That's a AAA battery for scale.

[image]
[image]
[image]

My question is: where can I find something that will screw into the threads in the base of the pump and somehow lead to a modern Presta pump head?

Comment: You could check with a local outfit that fabs hydraulic and air hoses for industrial purposes.

Comment: I think something like http://www.amazon.com/Sunlite-Bicycle-Replacement-Model-Floor/dp/B000AO5KCO could fit your needs. You would just have to check if the thread has the right size.

Comment: @Benedikt, I believe that's the core of my question. :) How can I check if the thread is the right size? Is there a name or spec for the threads that I have? How could I figure it out with normal household measuring tools?

Comment: Take it to a hardware store (when they're not busy) and see if they have a bolt or fitting that matches.  With any luck it's IPS.

Comment: Have you already thought about contacting Schwinn directly? As they are in the market for some years now, they may have some sense of tradition and may be able to tell you which thread you need o maybe even still have spare parts for your pump.

Comment: If you have a Schrader pump you can get these Presta adapters that screw onto the valve so that you can use a shrader pump on presta valves.  http://www.amazon.com/Innovations-In-Cycling-Inc-Adapter/dp/B001AT0YU6/

Comment: I have a similar problem. Schwinn AirDriver 1500, at least 15 yrs old. chuck has deteriorated so I can no longer use shrader, or chuck adapter for Presta. Cannot find chuck head, though hose is still good. Great pump, though.

Comment: FWIW, after my Topeak chuck failed this summer I bought [this](http://www.biketiresdirect.com/product/topeak-smarthead-hose-upgrade-kit?utm_campaign=products&utm_source=google&utm_medium=base&adl=1&gclid=CM-W8qDQj7kCFSRyQgod2yYAMw) replacement assembly -- just needed the chuck, but the chuck alone was out of stock and the price difference wasn't that much.  It might work for other pumps, perhaps with some surgery to the hose.

Comment: In principle, you could use a thread gauge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pitch_gauge
In practice, finding a nut that fits on your hose end or a machine screw that fits into your pump base will probably be easier. Be careful if you find one that _nearly_ fits, or it will chew up the existing thread.

Comment: @DanielRHicks is that not exactly the assembly he has, which he's made work, but not sustainably, with some surgery to the existing hose?

Comment: Also, if @tim-c is right about it being a pipe thread, it may be tapered, and you won't find any nut or screw that fits properly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_thread#Taper (The new Topeak connections use a rubber seal; I can't see from the photo if there's a rubber or fibre washer in the pump, or maybe one was lost. I'd be surprised if those flats are on a thread supposed to seal with a taper, but it's possible. It does look tapered, but maybe it's just unevenly worn.)

Comment: I believe that's a felt or leather washer stuck to the base in the 2nd photo, but I don't have the pump handy to verify.

Comment: I have the same pump, similar problem. My hose leaks where it inserts into pump, so I can't 'trim' it shorter. Did you solve the problem? Find a replacement hose that fits? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mitfch I gave up and bought a new pump years ago. I do still have the Schwinn and hope to restore it someday.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the size of that thread is called, "1/16 pipe thread" Find local places that make custom hydraulic hoses and verify the thread.  Then ask whether they have a fitting that is 1/16 male thread by hose barb.  Then you could eliminate all of the 30-year-old hose.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to very carefully cut off the piece of metal that crimps the existing hose onto the threaded part, and then reuse the threaded part by crimping the new hose onto it. The downside is that if it doesn't work, you can no longer even go on as you are, because you will no longer have any of the old hose left at all to join to. If you can find another hose that fits first, like maybe a one from a similar age frame pump (which would be too short to just use as is), that would be safer.

Yet another option (which could also be used if you try the option above and it fails) - pick one of the adapters that came with the new hose, and make the pump fit it, either by tapping it out to a larger thread that fits a larger adapter thread, or tapping it out to a larger thread and fitting a helicoil. Downside - if the new thread is too much larger, the base of the pump will break. (And if it's not larger enough, it won't hold the new adapter securely. You could cross thread it and then use epoxy, but that's getting pretty desperate.)

Answer (score 1):

A search online turned up nothing for a pump that old. If you have a model number or something else that identifies the pump, that may help get better answers. There are plenty of replacement hoses out there, but the photos don't really show a closeup of the threaded connection to the pump base. The only thing I can think of, would be to take the pump and the hose connection piece to an automotive shop where they can make their own high pressure hose fittings for vehicle applications like air conditioning type hoses. You would obviously need a smaller diameter hose, but it's possible they have smaller hoses for other high pressure applications. They may already have a threaded fitting that will work, or know where to get one. If they have or can get the fitting, then the correct diameter and length of hose should be easy. This would likely cost twice as much or more than you paid for the pump, but if it's a favorite, it may be worth it to you.

Answer (score 1):

I just ordered a Silca replacement hose and Schrader end for the same pump. Silca also makes a presta valve adapter. Check out the Silca website or Modern Bike.

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit in the part numbers and add links?

Answer (score -1):

This looks similar.  You could whack off the head and hopefully the hose inlet to the pump is the right size.
http://www.sears.com/custom-building-products-replacement-pump-hose-20inch/p-SPM6180332701?prdNo=10&blockNo=10&blockType=G10

It is listed as 3/16" hose connector.

Comment: The link doesn't work. It is better to show a picture an explanation of the item rather than provide a link to an online store as often links expire but a user may want to see the answer in the future.

Answer (score -1):

It's rather simple, just buy another hose in the length you need. There's common lengths of you can get one custom made at a hydraulic hose shop possibly.

A Google search of "Bicycle pump replacement hose" will pull up dozens and dozens of hoses in a variety of lengths, end fittings and colors.

Comment: Hi Chase, i'd like to think the OP has sorted this now as the original question goes back to Feb 2013, reading back through the post my understanding was the actual problem was the male connector into the actual pump. Yes you're right in suggesting that "Google" has lots of options for hose but unfortunately unless you know the specific size needed beforehand it's as useful as a chocolate fireguard.